# Label Encoding on multiple columns with same transformation on train and test set

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe with some columns and 10 of them are categorical, I want to label encode them using `LabelEncoder`. But, I want to use the same transformation on training and testing set. And I am doing this:

```
categorical_columns = train.columns[:10].tolist()       # List of categorical columns: [c0, c1, c2 ... c9]

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(categorical_columns)

train[categorical_columns] = le.transform(train[categorical_columns])
test[categorical_columns] = le.transform(test[categorical_columns])
```

But this code is giving me the fallowing error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-a43d4dd9a428> in <module>
      4 le.fit(categorical_columns)
      5 
----> 6 train[categorical_columns] = le.transform(train[categorical_columns])
      7 test[categorical_columns] = le.transform(test[categorical_columns])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in transform(self, y)
    270         """
    271         check_is_fitted(self)
--> 272         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    273         # transform of empty array is empty array
    274         if _num_samples(y) == 0:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    845     raise ValueError(
    846         "y should be a 1d array, "
--> 847         "got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape))
    848 
    849 

ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (300000, 10) instead.
```

How should I do it correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

`LabelEncoder` should be use to encode `y` values only.

You should use `sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder` to perform this operation for categorical `X` features.

As follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

X = [['Male', 'X'], ['Female', 'Y'], ['Female', 'Z']]
OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(X)
```

Which output:

```
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 2.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OneHotEncoder` to replace `LabelEncoder`:

```
>>> df
      Sex Cabin Embarked
0  female   C85        C
1  female  C123        S
2    male   E46        S
3  female    G6        S
4  female  C103        S
5    male   D56        S
6    male    A6        S
```

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

arr = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df).toarray()
```

```
>>> arr

#       Sex   , Cabin                         , Embarked 
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

To know more, read [this article](https://contactsunny.medium.com/label-encoder-vs-one-hot-encoder-in-machine-learning-3fc273365621) (a bit old)